# Rotate - Mechanism that changes direction

Tags: gears, mechanisms

I have a square plate (8x8 cm) that I want to turn it 90 degrees clockwise and after 90 degrees counterclockwise as you can see in the picture. Each rotate will happened after a second delay and fast (don't know exactly the speed but fast).

I know how to control gears etc but I want your help about the simplest implementation. I thought about solenoid or stepper motor or motor with a gear like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmA9Vnu33FY
[image]

What do you suggest?

Comment: Check out drill driven valve lapping tools.

Comment: A geneva wheel driven by an electric motor that hits limit switches wired to an H-bridge to revers direction.

Answer (score 1):

Any crank system attached to a flywheel will do.

Remember the old steam locomotives? Revers of that.

The wheel turns the handle back and forth.  The handle can be connected to your square at a point 135 degrees from a hinge and will go back and forth 90 degrees. the reciprocal play then is 90 degrees